# Hex Variables in C#

Tags: hex

Part of my code snippet is found below:

```
Byte[] blockdata = new Byte[16];
blockdata[0] = 0x12;
blockdata[1] = 0x13;
blockdata[2] = 0x14;
```

Alright.  The 12 in `(0x12)` is fixed.  What if I want to use a variable for it?
Example:

```
int m = 12;
blockdata[0] = 0xm;
```

In the above, `m` is supposed to be `12`. How will I do that?

Help me please. Thanks.

Comment: You are going the wrong way, or you are not telling us what are you REALLY trying to achieve. See, what will you use write if it's not `12` but `F5`? `int m = F5` won't work. What's your point in keeping `12` as `int m`?

Comment: You can always use hex at the original place: `int m = 0x12` too. If not, you will have a hard time with ABCDEF unless you use strings.

Comment: If you feel that an answer helped you, you could [accept that answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235).

Answer (score 2):

Another way to achieve your goal might be

```
int bInt = 12;
byte b = 0x1;
b = Convert.ToByte("0x" + bInt,16);
```

Answer (score 2):

Just convert:

- first to string
- then from string treating it as a hexadecimal representation

like this

```
int m = 12;

blockdata[0] = Convert.ToByte(m.ToString(), 16);
```

Test:

```
 // 18 == 0x12
Console.Write(String.Format("{0} == 0x{0:x}"), blockdata[0]);
```

Comment: Your answer above served my purpose.  Thank you very much.  My program is now working perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

The expression `0x12` is a compile-time constant which cannot be changed at runtime. Hexadecimal `12` is the same value as `18` decimal, so you can just use

```
blockdata[0] = 18
```

to assign the desired value. There is no necessity to initialize variables of type `Byte` with constants using the hexadecimal format.